# Scrolling in my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, uiscrollview

I need to trigger a scroll event and to a particular y-pos within an element in my web application. How will I do that. My element not the entire window and if its the case I can go for window.scrollTo(x, y). My element has the class A. So will the following jquery work?

```
$('.A').scrollTo(x,y)
```

But the above code does not produce the expected o/p.

I tried the following code after reading gokul shinde:

```
var scroller = $('.x-grid3-scroller'); 
var scrollerHeight = scroller.height;
 scroller.animate({
        scrollTop: scroller.offset({top:scrollerHeight, left:0})
    },'slow'
 );
```

still did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scrolTop() {
 $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".A").offset().top
  },'slow'
 );

}
```

```css
.A {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
}
.B {
  color: Green;
  Font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  
  <div class="B" onclick="scrolTop();">Click Here</div>
</div>
```

This Should help you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following code:
`var scroller = $('.x-grid3-scroller'); \n
    var scrollerHeight = scroller.height;
     scroller.animate({
            scrollTop: scroller.offset({top:scrollerHeight, left:0})
        },'slow'
     );`
still did not work :(